# AspectJ: How to log the successful completion of a method?

Tags: java, aspectj

So I am working with AspectJ to refactor my program to remove all logging calls from the main classes. Instead, all logging calls will occur via aspects. So far, here's what I've done successfully:

- Catching all exceptions. Since I already have my exception handling pretty unified to begin with (Exceptions propagate up call stack until they reach my controller, then get caught), this wasn't too difficult. Using handle(Exception) I've got every catch block tied to an aspect that will log the exception before the catch block executes.
- Debug information logging. Basic things like entering a particular method, etc. Again, relatively simple using before() and, sometimes, args() or thisJoinPoint.getArgs() to capture parameters.

The final thing I need to do, though, is properly log successful completion of key methods. Here is a minor example, of a block of code as it currently exists in my program, so I can better explain my meaning here:

```
private static void loadDefaultProperties(){
    defaultProperties = new Properties();

    try {
        defaultProperties.load(
                Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                        "default.properties"));

        if(defaultProperties.size() == 0){
            throw new IOException();
        }

        //THE CURRENT LOGGING LINE THAT NEEDS TO BE MOVED TO AN ASPECT
        LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO, Main.class.getName(),
                "loadDefaultProperties()",
                "Default Properties file loaded successfully");

    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        //THIS EXCEPTION IS LOGGED USING HANDLE(EXCEPTION) IN AN ASPECT
        displayExceptionDialog(ex);
    }
}
```

So, this method loads the default properties from the classpath. If it fails, an IOException is thrown. However, if an exception is not thrown, and it performs its task successfully, I want to log that as well.

This particular example is a relatively minor item that wouldn't be a huge deal to miss, but this is the style currently used everywhere in the application.

How would I configure a pointcut/advice in AspectJ to only run after this method completes, and recognize that it does so successfully?

PS. I've considered propagating the exception further up the call stack. That would allow me to use a simple after() returning(Object o) advice to accomplish this. If an exception is thrown, this advice will not run because the method won't return properly.

The problem with that is there aren't many levels higher than this in the call stack. This particular method in my example is called directly by my main method immediately following the program's initialization. In my controller class, there's only one level higher in the call stack for all of my methods there as well.

I guess I could do this, but I want to see if there's another option first, rather than pool all of those exceptions together in one place.

Comment: Have you tried using an `around` advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use a pointcut to wrap anything in the call stack, including `main()`:

```
public aspect WrapMain
{
    pointcut mainMethod() : execution(public static void main(String[]));
    before() : mainMethod() {
        System.out.println("Starting application...");
    }
    after() : mainMethod() {
        System.out.println("Terminating application...");
    }
}
```

If you are generating aspects using Java, you can use the [`@AfterReturning`](http://www.java2novice.com/spring/aop-aspectj-afterreturning-annotation/) and [`@AfterThrowing`](http://java2novice.com/spring/aop-aspectj-afterthrowing-annotation/) annotations to manage successful or exceptional cases.

```
@Pointcut("execution(your-method-signature-here)
public void yourPointcut(){}

@AfterReturning(pointcut = "yourPointcut()", returning ="returnValue")
public void afterSuccessAdvice(JoinPoint jp, Object returnValue) {
    // log here
}

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "yourPointcut()", returning ="returnValue")
public void afterFailureAdvice(JoinPoint jp, Object returnValue) {
    // log here
}
```

Here's a [Javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072449/logging-method-entry-exit-with-spring-aspectj.html) article with examples that explains logging method entry and exit.